# Dynamically set return types based on keys of interface passed

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want a function to return an object whose keys are equal to the array of keys of an interface passed to the function.

```js
interface T { /* ...*/ }
func(keys: Array<keyof T>) => Object whose keys exactly match the argument `keys`.
```

Example:

```js
interface Student {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  id: number;
}

const result = func(['name', 'age']);
result.name // ok
result.age // ok
result.id // should be an error
```

Here's the closest I got with actual code, but it doesn't work.

```js
class PersonInfo { constructor(field: string){} }

type GetInfo<T> = (fields: Array<keyof T>) => Record<keyof T, PersonInfo>;

const getInfo: GetInfo<Student> = (fields: Array<keyof Student>): Record<keyof Student, PersonInfo> => {
  const result: Record<keyof Student, PersonInfo> = {}; // Compile error because it doesn't contain all keys of Student.
  for (const field of fields) {
    result[field] = new PersonInfo(field);
  }

  return result;
};

const info = getInfo(['name', 'age']);
info.name // ok
info.age // ok
info.id // should be an error, but it's not
```

I also tried the following, but of course won't compile because `keyof` cannot be used on a value.

```js
type GetInfo<T> = <U extends keyof T>(fields: Array<keyof T>) => { [key in keyof fields]: string };
```

How can I reference the contents of the array which is passed to the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
interface Student {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  id: number;
}

function getInfo<T extends keyof Student>(keys: T[]): Pick<Student, T> {
  // your impl ..
}

const info = getInfo(['name']);

info.name; // ok
info.id; // TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Pick<Student, "name">'.
```