# How can I set return value based on key of interface with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am in a scenario where I need to proxy calls to an API.

I want to make a call like `proxy('theMethod', arg1, arg2);`

The goal is that when you call through proxy, you still know the proper return type of the called method.

I have made a [simple TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIAUCSyDeBYAKGWORgHsyAuZACgEpkBeAPmXSjIFtgBnCAHgBGFADYQ4IZgBpCJZILhRq9Jq3ZdeAkAFdOg6M0IBfQoQRkQPMMjAALCKgAOwahmyNcskuSq0GLNg5uPgA6KAgeMhEANwgaMChtCDoZIhIFJT9VQI1Q8MiYuIBGOmNTAjgeAE8QBFJtWrBgC2RHDgAPKv4AFWQIdsgQABMeZABrCCqyGDQsZhpOCDsyIepuumoc4IF0YAQx-jcpZG7mVnw08LBtKBAbeydgAG1F5aGAXXoAbjKCMwsrMhOFUAEpLG53DxtMidGgAch8cLoXyAA) showing things aren't working as expected. I didn't bother with the arguments in the sample cause that doesn't seem to matter for what the error is.

```js
interface API {
    foo: () => Promise<boolean>,
    bar: () => Promise<number>
}

const theApi: API = {
    foo: () => Promise.resolve(true),
    bar: () => Promise.resolve(1)
}

async function proxy<T extends keyof API>(method: T):  Promise<Pick<API, T>> {
  return theApi[method]();
}

const myReturn = proxy('foo');
```

It gives the following error:

```
Type 'Promise<boolean> | Promise<number>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Pick<API, T>>'.
  Type 'Promise<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Pick<API, T>>'.
    Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Pick<API, T>'.(2322)
```

Meanwhile, the return type of `myReturn` in the playground is not accurately saying it should be `Promise<boolean>`. It gets back `Promise<Pick<API, "foo">`

I had based this on [Dynamically set return types based on keys of interface passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60921616/dynamically-set-return-types-based-on-keys-of-interface-passed)

What am I missing here?

Comment: @jcalz I just updated question with playground to make it way clearer :)

Comment: `Pick<{ a: string, b: string }, 'a'>` is `{ a: string }`. This is almost certainly not what you want here.

Comment: What is your goal here, to have different predefined ways to do proxy calls?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w1Egyw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz you got me to what I needed in that I did not know I can do `MyType[K]` where `K` can reference just like an object! Your answer suffices for the playground. My actual proxy method is not so direct and it fails, but `: Promise<ReturnType<CAIAPI[T]>>` works in my real code and not the playground. I don't know enough to know the difference. I think your comment and be used as answer for this question though!

Comment: So you were just looking for [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) instead of `Pick`?  What about the fact that [your code still errors even with that fix](https://tsplay.dev/N754EW)?  The refactoring with `APIMap` is necessary for the compiler to follow your logic.  Do you want me to write up an answer about this or not?

Comment: Just to be clear here, you're happy with something like `Promise<Awaited<ReturnType<API[K]>>>` even though the body of the function can't be verified as type safe?  That's certainly easier for me to write.  Shall I do that?